# Android how to enable open with

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I couldn't find a proper heading for this question . In my android app I have a music player , which can play mp3 file of my device . What I want that  when user try to open a mp3 file user should given a option that would you like to open this file with "my music app" . Or in the other hand "my music app" should be enlisted with in "open with option"

Comment: does any app open up when you click on any mp3 file?

Comment: yes , there are three other app which open up

Comment: [register as music player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768379/register-as-music-player) , this is might what are you looking for .

Comment: @aroSuv check shuvro's method about Manifest and IntentFilter

Answer (score 2):

read this page for add your app to "what program do you wish to use" dialog
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)