# Register as music player and play song

Tags: java, android, audio, android-intent

I'm creating a music player app and I want to register the app as a music player. So that when a user clicks on any song to play, my app should be suggested as one of the music players. I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768379/register-as-music-player) .

After I added the necessary code in manifest.xml, it only shows my app in suggestions. When I select my app, nothing is played. I think there should be something like receiver in main activity to receive the media path to play the selected song. But I don't know how to implement this.

I've added following code to my manifest.xml (for reference):

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I`m pretty sure that's what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33783826/7094632

Comment: yes this isn't working

Answer (score 2):

Once you added IntentFilters use getIntent() to get the data from it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(@NonNull final Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        try {
            IntentHandler.onActionView(intent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

IntentHandler.java

```
final class IntentHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "IntentHandler";

    private IntentHandler() {

    }

    static void onActionView(@NonNull final Intent intent) throws IOException {
        final Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Intent data is null");
            throw new IOException("Intent data is null");
        }

        final String scheme = data.getScheme();
        if (scheme == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Uri scheme is null");
            throw new IOException("Uri scheme is null");
        }
        switch (scheme) {
            case "file":
                playFile(data);
                break;

            case "content":
                playContent(data);
                break;

            case "http":
                playHttp(data);
                break;

            default:
                Log.w(TAG, "Unhandled Uri scheme: " + scheme);
                throw new IOException("Unhandled Uri scheme: " + scheme);
        }
    }

    private static void playFile(@NonNull final Uri data) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "playFile() path = " + data.getPath());
        // Play a plain file
    }

    private static void playContent(@NonNull final Uri data) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "playContent() " + data);
        // Use ContentResovler to query the Uri
    }

    private static void playHttp(@NonNull final Uri data) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "playHttp() " + data);
        // Play from network
    }
}
```

If you don't support playing from ContentProvider or from network remove IntentFilter for "http" or "content" scheme accordingly from AndroidManifest.xml

**Edit**: You could use switch-case statement instead of a bunch of "if" in the `handleIntent()` method if you don't want your code to look ugly in the future. The code should looked like this:

```
private void handleIntent(@NonNull final Intent intent) {
    switch (intent.getAction())
    {
        case Intent.ACTION_VIEW:
        {
            try {
                IntentHandler.onActionView(intent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle error
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try these intent filters ?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
    ...
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\.mp3"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\.ogg"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\.wav"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\.wma"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\.flac"/>
    ...
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then in your activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Uri u = i.getData();
    String a = i.getAction();

    if ((u != null) && (a != null) && (a.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.VIEW")))
    {   String filename = null;

        if (i.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("file"))
        {   filename = u.getPath();
        }
        else if (i.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("content"))
        {   try
            {   String[] filepathcolumn = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(u, filepathcolumn, null, null, null);
                cursor1.moveToFirst();
                int columnindex1 = cursor1.getColumnIndex(filepathcolumn[0]);
                filename = cursor1.getString(columnindex1);
                cursor1.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {   e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (filename != null)
        {   ...
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code below

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="audio/*" />
     </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you only define the default music player when song is selected
>   in Manifest file and also write the code for service which run in the
>   Main Thread to play the song.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="-1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
```